# Can I use admob rewarded ads to remove banner ads?

Tags: android, admob

I have an app. Where I shows Banner & Interstitial ads to users.
I want to give user an option to temporary remove ads for 1 day using Rewarded ads.

Is that legal? Can I use rewarded ads to remove Banner & Interstitial ads?

Comment: I did the same to remove ads for 2 days, but in my app nobody used that. Only 1% of users watch videos and the rest 99% download videos for nothing. Reviews that complain about ads are not reduced since this is not a long term solution for them. I advise to implement in-app purchases to remove ads.

Comment: Thanks for the statistics. I will think about in-app purchases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is being said about this specific situation in Admob policies, not even in Admob's "Rewarded inventory policy" therefor I would consider it legal.

You may find more information on that topic on Admob's help site:
[Admob Help: Rewarded inventory policy](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7313578?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287)

Comment: Yes I have also try to search and read about there policy. I have tried to contact them as well but no reply from them yet.

Answer (score 2):

Since nothing like that is forbidden by the [policy](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7313578?hl=en) it should be allowed. First try to calculate your balance - one rewarded ad would probably bring you less money than a banner shown for 1 day.
If it suits you don't worry and implement this feature, it seems totally legit.

Answer (score 1):

Why should it be a problem? Ads from adMob give you money based on how many times they are seen and/or clicked by users, so if you remove ads for one day you're the only one who get lost.

The important thing is that you describe well what the user obtains form the rewarded ad.

Answer (score 1):

If you check out [this](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3269069?hl=en) link, you can see that it states:

"**An impression is counted when one or more pixels of the ad creative is visible on a device's screen.**"

You can decide whether to display the ad or not. It's up to you to decide how your app behaves.

In one of my android app [My Pad](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shaheershukur.mypad) , i had added option for users to disable ads.